# How to check for equality between elelements in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, element, equality

I have this vector

```
std::vector<int> vec = {3,4,5,5};
```

and I want to check for equality between the elements in a vector. In this case 5 is equal to 5. I want to store these elements in another vector and to save their positions (offsets) in another variable.

EDIT: //THIS DOESN'T WORK

```
std::vector<int> vec = {3, 4, 5, 5};
std::vector<int> store;
std::vector<int> offset;

int len = vec.size();

for(int count = 0; count + 1 < len; count++)
{
  if(vec.at(count) == vec.at(count + 1))
  {
     store.push_back(vec.at(count));
     offset = count;
  }
}
```

The output should be:

```
store = {5,5};
offset.at(0) = 2;
offset.at(1) = 3;
```

Comment: And what actually stops you to do `vec[2] == vec[3]`??

Comment: I want to compare the elements in for loop maybe? Because I have many vectors and I don't know their elements, this was just an example what I really want to do. :)

Comment: [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find)?

Comment: @malicization Well, replace `2` and `3` with `i` and `i + 1` and take care that `(i + 1) < vec.size()` when doing that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I don't actually understand what you described, because I can't compare i with i+1 in a for loop

Comment: @malicization I said ***replace*** that in what I showed you 1st: `vec[i] == vec[i+1]`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ and the condition is i+1 < vec.size() ?

Comment: @malicization check with an `if` or in the `for` loop condition.

Comment: @malicization What is the actual goal?  Is it store duplicates and their positions?  If so, then a `std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>>` would seem to be more appropriate.

Comment: @malicization Are these elements always sorted?

Comment: And also want to store the both elements (10).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes

Comment: *and to save their position (offset) as integer type in another variable.* -- I don't quite understand.  How are you going to store multiple positions if you're only going to use one variable?  Why not put in your post an illustration of what you want the **final** output to look like, or at least a representation of the final output.  Your description of what you like to see is very hazy.  For example, `{3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10}`.  What is the output for everything you're describing?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've edited it again.

Answer (score 1):

This will count repetitions, but not adjacent too.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8};
    std::vector<int> store;
    std::vector<int> offset;

    int pos {0};

    for (auto v : vec)
    {
        int c = std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), v);
        if (c > 1) {
            store.push_back(v);
            offset.push_back(pos);
        }
        ++pos;
    }
    for (auto v : store)
        std::cout << "Repeated: " << v << std::endl;

    for (auto v : offset)
        std::cout << "Offsets: " << v << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```